# What's faster: passing an array to a class and doing a for each loop, or doing a for each loop on a class

Tags: java, arrays, performance, class

I was wondering which method would be correct in terms of performance and best practice.

I have an array of URLs, I am scraping the content of these pages. I have a separate class to handle the scraping.

Currently I pass the array list to the class, the class then loops through the array contents scraping the contents for each array. I believe this to be the best way.

The other way I was thinking of was looping through the array, and I would pass each URL to the class. This seems like it would be slower to me but I'm not sure.

If the two methods are both viable then what are their pro's and con's?

Comment: Sound like micro and premature optimization - do whatever is more readable... If you will later profile your program and see that this part is a botleneck, you might want to consider refactor - but until then - it does not worth your time to modify it.

Comment: There's no way this could mean anything in terms of performance. Loop management is a microscopically, vanishingly small part of your procedure.

Comment: What amit says is true. If you are parsing any strings or doing any network communication you will not notice any difference in creating objects. So always go for best maintainable and optimize only when you have a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest you do what you believe is the clearest and simplest.

Passing the array might be marginally fastest and might save a few nano-seconds, but unless what you are doing is of the order of a few nano-seconds, it is highly unlikely you will be able to tell the difference.

Comment: Thank you very much, I wasn't sure if either method would have a noticeable impact on my app. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: each method call can add a few ns, so if you call it a billion times thats a few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, passing each item to the class would be slower due to the added overhead of a method call per page (assuming this is what you are doing):

```
URLProcessor up = new URLProcessor();
for(String url: URLs) {
   up.process(url); // method call for each URL
}
```

instead of:

```
up.process(URLs); // a single method call
```

However, most likely this will not influence the running speed in a noticeable way, unless the method is called millions of times. There are far more heavyweight tasks happening in a program than this.